# How do I determine how long it will take to pay off my all my loans?

Tags: loans, calculation, debt-reduction

Right now I have a spreadsheet with the loans I have, the interest rates the are each at, and how much I am putting toward each in monthly payments. I then calculate how long each loan will take to pay off individually by using `=NPER(INTEREST_RATE/12,PAYMENT_AMOUNT,CURRENT_LOAN_AMOUNT)`.

This works (to my knowledge), but does not take into consideration that when one of the loans is paid off, I would like to take the money I would have spent on that loan and apply it to the next highest interest loan.

Is there a way to apply that sort of logic easily? Or do I have to just determine when each loan would be paid off and have a separate model for when that happens?

Comment: Try http:powerpay.org which has built into it all the functionality that you want to construct for yourself.

Comment: "Is there a way to apply that sort of logic easily? " ... you may get better / faster answer on superuser.com. Just put an image of the spreadsheet showing your calculations and your ask. Someone should be able to tell you a formulae or macro that can easily be written of.

Comment: What you are talking about is called payment snowballing. Here is a link to an [excel spreadsheet from lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/download-this-snowball-debt-calculator-and-plan-to-get-1309942724).

Comment: **Pay off the highest interest loans first** this will help maximise debt repayment.

Answer (score 1):

## Multi-Loan Debt Payment Time Calculations

#### Calculation Recipe

To calculate how long it will take to pay off multiple loans you can perform the following calculations:

1. Determine the monthly available money (*P<sub>max</sub>*) and the minimum payment of loan 2 (*P<sub>2min</sub>*).
2. Determine *NPER<sub>1</sub>*, the `NPER()` of loan 1 using the maximum available money minus the minimum payment of loan 2 (*P<sub>max</sub>* - *P<sub>2min</sub>*).
3. Determine *FV<sub>2min</sub>*, the `FV()` of making minimum payments on loan 2 for the number of periods it take to pay off loan 1 (*NPER<sub>1</sub>*).
4. Determine *NPER<sub>2</sub>*, the `NPER()` of loan 2 with the reduced balance (*FV<sub>2min</sub>*) using the maximum available payment (*P<sub>max</sub>*).
5. Calculate *NPER<sub>Total</sub>*, by adding the two (*NPER<sub>1</sub>* + *NPER<sub>2</sub>*).

#### Example Spreadsheet

`B9` and `D9` contain the `NPER()` formulas that you referenced and I have highlighted `D2` that contains the `FV()` calculation for Loan 2.  The Total Time result is in `B12`.  There are also some other helpful calculations, to provide insight into the total debt, but these are not needed for the time calculation.  Comment if you need the formulas.

[image: example debt calculation]